# Multiple IF statement in one calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time, isblank

I have tried everything, can someone help me with this?

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date1]),DATEDIF([Created],[Date2],"d"),IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Date1),DATEDIF([Date1],[Date2],"d"))))
```

It keeps saying unsupported syntax in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date1]), DATEDIF([Created], [Date2], "d"), IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Date1)), DATEDIF([Date1], [Date2], "d"), ""))
```

OR

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date1]), DATEDIF([Created], [Date2], "d"), DATEDIF([Date1], [Date2], "d"))
```

**Note**:

Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date1]),DATEDIF([Created],[Date2],"d"),DATEDIF([Date1],[Date2],"d"))
```